# what is the better way to give a string default value if it is null in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code like below. It initiates an instance of `Model`. There are some values like `json['status']` can be `null`. What is the best way to give them a default value `''`? I am from javascript world, so I am looking for a way like `json['status'] || ''`.

```dart
factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Model(
        id: json['id'],
        status: json['status'],
        amount: json['amount'],
        scheme: json['scheme'],
        type: json['type']);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the null-coalescing (`??`) operator as follows:

```
factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Model(
        id: json['id'] ?? 0,
        status: json['status'] ?? 'status',
        amount: json['amount'] ?? 0,
        scheme: json['scheme'] ?? 'scheme',
        type: json['type'] ?? 'defaultType');
  }
```

You can also read more about null-aware operators in the official [Dart cheatsheet](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet).